# Wordpress get_terms returns empty array for custom taxonomy

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

i have a bit problem with Wordpress Taxonomies... Below you can see initialization of my custom taxonomy named `job_keywords`.

```
function register_job_keywords() {

    $labels = array(
        [... lables here ...]
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'job_keywords', array( 'job' ), $args );
}
```

I also implement it into custom post type `job`.

```
$args = array(
    [...]
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'job_category' , 'job_keywords'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    [...]
```

In *plugin init* i call function `register_job_keywords()` which makes me see keywords in *wp-admin* and i can add them just like *tags* etc. So everything works fine in interface and i go to my *php* file and show all the taxonomies. So i got this :

```
Array
(
    [category] => category
    [post_tag] => post_tag
    [nav_menu] => nav_menu
    [link_category] => link_category
    [post_format] => post_format
    [job_category] => job_category
    [job_keywords] => job_keywords
)
```

As you can see `job_keywords` exists.
But if i want to use `get_terms('job_keywords')` it return : 
`Array( )`

Why that so?
I want to notice two things. Ones , i use `print_r` to see terms. Second , i already added some *keywords* in wp-admin interface.

Any suggestions? I hope you can help me :)

Comment: I'm not sure but i suggest you to try out `get the terms`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, i got the answer.
`get_terms( 'job_keywords', array("hide_empty" => false) );`
**get_terms** have default `hide_empty => true` and my keywords are not used by any post.

From wordpress:

> Default is true. Will not return empty terms, which means terms whose
>   count is 0 according to the given taxonomy.

Comment: thanks a bunch bhai saab. you are an angel